# Javascript Module with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about javascript module pattern with JQuery.

Im a little confused about how i should use jquery. I have all my javascript modules in seperate files.

Lets say I have a small module

```
var jqueryTest = (function () {
  function privateMethod() {
    $("input[type=submit], a, button")
      .button()
      .click(function () {
        alert("ALARM");
      });
  }

  return {
    test: function () {
      privateMethod();
    }
  };
})();
```

I then call the module from my index and it works.

I then tried to pass JQuery as a parameter like this

```
var jqueryTest = (function (jq) {
  function privateMethod() {
    jq("input[type=submit], a, button")
      .button()
      .click(function () {
        alert("ALARM");
      });
  }

  return {
    test: function () {
      privateMethod();
    }
  };
})(JQuery);
```

But then it stops working?

The word "JQuery" thats passed as a parameter, what does this refer to?

And how should I use JQuery when having the javascript in different files?

Hope someone can help

Comment: Do you import the jQuery file before your own ? BTW you should replace "stops working" by the exact error in your question. If you don't know how to use the console, please learn that before everything else.

Comment: "But then it stops working?" Are you getting errors in the console, because that code should work ok.

Comment: [Here's a demo of it working ok](http://jsfiddle.net/u23abfne/1/).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was not getting any errors. What does jquery parameter refer to? Is it the filename of the jquery file? And could i pass in fx. a Devexpress or syncfusion js file?

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo. its `jQuery`. not `JQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery instead of JQuery:

Example:

```
html:
<div id="myDiv"></div>

javascript:

var jqueryTest = (function (jq) {
    jq("#myDiv").html('<label>Hi there!</label>');
    return "hi " + jq("#myDiv").text();
})(jQuery);

alert(jqueryTest);
```